# How to set multiple settings.py for sites framework django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-settings

Am trying to set up multiple website with same base. While browsing, came to know Django has Sites framework which I could use.

I didnt get how to set multiple settings.py file with site id. Any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I followed this document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/.

Answer (score 1):

you can have multiple setting file for example develop.py and production.py

steps:

1. create a settings folder inside the project
2. Add all of the settings file to that folder
3. while running server

   ```bash
   ./manage.py runserver -- settings=project_name.settings.required_settingfile
   ```

for example:

```
./manage.py runserver --settings=myproject.settings.develop
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip. Is there any way we can make this on wsgi. I have an apache2 server

Comment: import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname() according to hostname we can select the  required setting file in wsgi.

Comment: ok thanks. Just one doubt, then why do we have site id for settings file. I thought django can handle it

Comment: sorry i dont know  about the site_id.let me check and post here

Answer (score 1):

To serve multiple sites from the same Django instance you do not need multilple settings.py files.

A simple method is to omit the `SITE_ID` setting from the Sites framework. Then include the [Sites framework middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/#site-middleware):

```
'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware'
```

This automatically passes a `request` object to `Site.objects.get_current()` on every request. It also allows your Django application to detect the current site via `request.site`.

You would need to make sure to setup multilple virtual hosts using your NGINX or apache instance to route traffic from each site to your server.