# Django: What is the proper way to include multiple settings.py files (or include a dynamic SITE_ID) using the sites framework?

Tags: django, django-sites

I'm getting this error on my Django site in production:

> You're using the Django "sites framework" without having set the SITE_ID setting. Create a site in your database and set the SITE_ID setting or pass a request to Site.objects.get_current() to fix this error.

The question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40648755/2532070) but the accepted answer suggests using `runserver` in production.

It has also been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41934906/2532070) but the accepted answer is inscrutable.

I've tried adding the following to my `settings.py` file but it throws an error:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
SITE_ID = Site.objects.get_current()
```

the error is:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

...but I do have the SECRET_KEY setting set.

What is the proper way to follow the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/) to server multiple sites on the same server?

Answer (score 1):

The answer here was to include the [Sites framework middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/#site-middleware):

```
'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware'
```

This automatically passes a `request` object to `Site.objects.get_current()` on every request per the error notification.